# Windows cmd dir hogging CPU

Tags: windows, windows-10, cpu-usage, dir

[image]

I have a couple of these "Windows command Processor" (`cmd`) running a `dir` command and taking 10-15% CPU constantly, heating everything up and well hogging CPU.

I also see `findstr` running around the same time, not sure if it's related.

Command running looks like `ls -lR` equivalent. No idea what is running that.

I opened "Indexing Options", it says "index complete". So not sure if it's indexing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try killing the process and see if it pops up again. If it does not, you may have to try clean booting to see if the problem is present.

EDIT: the two processes are almost certainly related. They seem to be related to indexing. Please open the resource monitor (`Win+R` and type `resmon`) and post screenshot of the process.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Windows Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).  It should show you which program or service started these processes.  Process Explorer is a freeware task manager and system monitor for Microsoft Windows.